# Wifi connection issues on Ubuntu 16.04 RTL8188EE

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have a HP notebook, which had Windows 7 (or 10, can't remember) by default, deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu 16.04. I'm quite a newb, anyway. The thing is, I'm having connection issues, having the wifi disconnected randomly. I solve the problem from time to time by pressing the airplane button 2 times, so the wireless connection gets reset.
I did this:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

Then I get the following:

```
   *-network    
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp7s0
       versión: 07
       serie: b0:5a:da:ce:ae:bd
       tamaño: 10Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
       driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:43 ioport:5000(size=256) memoria:d6000000-d6000fff memoria:d6100000-d6103fff
  *-network
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:13:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp19s0
       versión: 01
       serie: 18:4f:32:00:30:94
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.50 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       recursos: irq:50 ioport:3000(size=256) memoria:d3000000-d3003fff
```

So what can I do?

Comment: Does it happen on a wired connection (i.e., ethernet)? How about when running Ubuntu on a Live CD (without installing)?

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether power management is causing issues with wifi by changing a value in the relevant configuration file:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

and reboot.

If it doesn't work, you can revert back with this command and reboot again:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 2/wifi.powersave = 3/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Comment: oh wow that's interesting. Is there any documentation that explains this config? What do the numbers mean?

Comment: 0 (use default), 1 (ignore/don't touch), 2 (disable), or 3 (enable)